# Prevent background disappearing

Tags: css

So I've got a body with a CSS gradient background. Then I've got an absolute positioned div nested just within that with a background overlay. In turn, the content wrapper div is then nested within this. I want background div to be fixed and the web page to scroll over the top. The problem is, when the page scrolls the background overlay div kind of disappears like a roller blind...

Here's my fiddle to demonstrate the issue... http://jsfiddle.net/WPk6h/ (try scrolling the result pane to see the effect I mean).

HTML....

```
<body>
    <div id="bgwrapper">
        <div id="wrapper">
            Content...
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

and CSS...

```
body {
    background-color:#fcf
}
#bgwrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;width:100%;height:100%;
    background: transparent url(http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/big/big-smiley-001.gif) no-repeat right bottom;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;    
}
#wrapper {
    width:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any ideas how to prevent this so that the background overlay remains visible at all times?

note... I've not tested it heavily in all browsers yet - the issue is in the first browser I've been using, Chrome so I haven't got round to testing in others yet.

EDIT...

People are wondering why I don't just apply the background image to the HTML or BODY tags - well, there is a clash between CSS gradients and background images - you cannot have them both in the same element, as can be seen with the two examples below. This is why I'm using an additional background wrapper div to create the effect of an 5% alpha image overlaying the gradient bg.

http://jsfiddle.net/tqbtm/ (attempting to add gradient *and* bg image to body tag)

http://jsfiddle.net/ca5wa/ (adding bg image to bg wrapper div *over* the body gradient)

Comment: don't get the point of the `bgwrapper`: http://jsfiddle.net/WPk6h/3/

Comment: Fair comment, @Pete. Basically, if you're using CSS gradients you cannot also apply an image to the background - compare this http://jsfiddle.net/ca5wa/ where the body has a gradient and the #bgwrapper has the image, and this http://jsfiddle.net/tqbtm/ where I attempt to add both the gradient *and* image bg to the body

Comment: ah right, didn't know you were using gradients

Comment: :) The first sentence in my OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `position: absolute` from `#bgwrapper` div:

```
#bgwrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: transparent url(http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/big/big-smiley-001.gif) no-repeat right bottom;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;    
}
```

[Update jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WPk6h/1/)

Comment: Well that certainly seems to have done the trick, but I'll confess to being slightly confused - surely absolute positioning would have been necessary to take the div out of the DOM flow?? I'm going to have a head scratch for a couple of minutes :) Backson...

Comment: when the div was positioned absolutely the height was being set to the viewport height with `height:100%`and the text content was flowing out of it. If you had set `overflow:hidden` on `#bgwrapper` the content would also have been cut at the same point as the image disappearing. Removing the positioning keeps the div in the DOM flow and as it scrolls the background stays fixed.

Comment: also add `margin:0` to the body to negate default styling and remove the space before the image - http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/WPk6h/5/

Comment: Awesome - got it. I was having trouble implementing this on my actual dev site but I had height:100% on both the HTML and BODY tags - as soon as I removed that it started working. I understand why not `position:absolute` now too - basically the `background-position:fixed` kind of provides that effect - the background is fixed and the DIV is going anywhere relative to the DOM as the page scrolls, so the background stays put. Thanks Morpheus :)

Comment: Thanks @Duncan Beattie - That was just a scruffy bit of code put together to demonstrate my problem - my dev site has taken care of all that :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at the following link:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

which details several different methods of doing full-screen, fixed, backgrounds

the method I currently use is method 1 (CSS3) for this kind of technique

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kolin - a handy resource but not massively applicable to me at the moment because my body CSS gradient throws a bit of a spanner in the works :) I usually use the technique you mention too but I tend to add that to the BODY tag itself... my body tag is currently being used for the background gradient. I guess I could have experimented with setting the gradient on the HTML and the bg image on the BODY but it's working now... if it ain't broke, and all that! :)

Answer (score 1):

As Doug told you just add `background-attachment:fixed;` `background-size:cover;`  `width:100%;` `height:100%;` to your #bgwrapper style.

Comment: Sorry, but all of these properties were already in my CSS... the key was to remove the absolute positioning.

Comment: Sorry, I really apologize I will delete the reply but could you please upvote, I don't want to lose ratings :( I will upvote on your solution because of the reply I left

Comment: OK - but I believe you need to edit the answer before I can change my vote.

Comment: Yep - down vote removed... sorry, I didn't notice that you had so little reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Position to be fixed

```
position:fixed
```

In ...

```
#bgwrapper{
 position:fixed
 top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;width:100%;height:100%;

    background: transparent url(http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/big/big-smiley-001.gif) no-repeat right bottom;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;    
}
```

Comment: @Doug Eh, it wasn't and still isn't. Am I missing something? It currently reads position:absolute in the question and in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WPk6h/ it is also position:absolute. When I changed it to position:fixed in the fiddle earlier it fixed your problem. Removal now fixes it.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and I am shamed, @Rob Kielty! I misunderstood you for background-attachment:fixed. If you would be so kind as to edit your answer just slightly I will remove my downvote. I apologise for the confusion. The final solution, however, involved simply removing the whole position declaration entirely - it just didn't need it.

Comment: @Doug no need for shame!  Glad you got sorted out, that's the main thing.